# Convert spark row object to java pojo

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In Spark we can convert the Dataset to Java POJO using df.as[POJO].

I have a use case where I am joining two datasets and want to convert the Row object to Java POJO.

Row Object Schema after join:
root
- customerId
- messageId
- c1
- c2
- c3

Java POJO
root:
- customerId: String
- messageId: String
- content: List[Map]

After conversion:
root:
- customerId
- messageId
- content: [{c1: v1, c2: v2, c3: v3}]

Currently what approach I am following is I am converting the Row object to JSON and then convert JSON to POJO using ObjectMapper and it is a two step process which have cost of conversion and we have to apply this transformation to billion rows.

Is there is any better approach available to convert Row Object to Java POJO without converting to JSON and without using reflection or any By Default Scala to Java converters are available. I Know in Scala we have 'asInstanceof' available but I am not sure if something similar is available in Java.

Comment: It is not quite clear what you want to achieve, an example in code would be better.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have these:
two Java bean classes, A and B for short; and data of types Dataset[A] and Dataset[B].

You are joining them and result is DataFrame (or Dataset[Row] in other words) and you want to convert resulting type of Dataset back to some bean class.

Simplest way is to create Java bean class (or case class if you are using Scala in your application), which contains all fields of join between A and B (say it'd be named C). And use conversion via DataFrame.as[C].

This would result in what I understand you want without intermediate conversions to and from JSON.

Comment: But when I am joining the Dataset[A] and Dataset[B] it results into row object which contain all the columns from both dataset. Now my POJO has different structure so I cannot directly use .as[C] here. Instead I am using .map() function which takes in Row Object and spits out the POJO. According to example given of POJO i have to custom map content from joined dataset. Also I am not sure if .as[C] can give me the expected result.

Comment: What stops you from trying this out?